# Typescript + RxJS: how to map an observable to run a loop?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to understand how to map an observable to a loop

The code looks like this:

```
let count = now.getFullYear() - this.startYear + 1;
let start = this.startYear;

let allYears = Array.apply(0, Array(count))
  .map(function (element, index) {
    return index + start;
  });

// from is in `import {from} from "rxjs/observable/from";`
let yearEmitter = from(allYears);

let createCustomer = this.customerService.create(); // an http call to return a customer in Json
let createMember = createCustomer.map(c => this.customerService.createMember(c["customerId"])); // an http call to return a member in Json 

createMember.map(member=> {
  // ??? what can I do here? 
  // I need to map it to another observable here for every year 
})
```

Basically, for the created member, I want to run a report from the start year to current year.

I can't do `allYear.foreach( i => createMember.map( blab ) )` , because this seems will call the createMember multiple times.

Recap, a sample data could be: `startYear = 2015`,

Then when `createMember` is returned, it should contain a memberId, which can be used to generate report (I need to generate sample report for a new member for testing purpose).

Hence, in a range of `(2015, 2016, 2017)`, I want to map the new member to loop through the items in that list, and make another http call to create sample report. I do not need any output, I just need to chain the `createMember` observable multiple times, but ideally, I only want to make the `createMember` http call once.

Hope it make more sense now.

OK, I think I might be overthinking it.

I could just do `createMember.subscribe` and then loop through it. /facepalm

I was thinking in a scala way that I can `flatMap` that thing, and then loop it in a for-comprehension. I guess I don't have to

Comment: `let createCustomer` is an Observable? If so, what kind of contents does it hold? 1 single emission with an array, 1 single emission with an object? multiple emissions? - also: it would help if you could add an example of how you would like the result to look like

Comment: sorry, let me add more details

Comment: Sorry, I still don't fully understand, what exactly you are trying to do - but it looks like it should be a very simple case and you maybe found a solution already - if you have please post it as an answer and accept your own  answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
createMember.switchMap(member => {
    let report = [];
    allYear.foreach(i => report[i] = getMySpecialValue(i);
    return Observable.of(report);
}
```